What number of confirmations is considered secure in Polygon?
In Bitcoin, 4 confirmations are considered secure (very low probability of transaction/block reversal).
What is the current number in Polygon?

I've read somewhere that 50 confirmations is generally safe. However there were bigger reorgs in the past (example with 157 blocks), so you may want to increase this number if you want to be super safe.
Here https://polygonscan.com/blocks_forked?p=1 you can find the reorgs that happened recently. For example, in the past two weeks the biggest reorg involved 27 blocks.
The only CEX I found that listed the number of confirmations is Kraken, which  requires 450 confirmations (link).
